# How can I get sizeof a vector::value_type?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, sizeof, value-type

I want to get `sizeof` of the type that is contained in a vector. Here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint> vecs;
    std::cout << sizeof(vecs.value_type) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

From my understanding this should be correct. However, when compiling with GCC 4.8.1 this is what I get:

```
test-sizeof.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test-sizeof.cpp:7:27: error: invalid use of ‘std::vector<unsigned int>::value_type’
  std::cout << sizeof(vecs.value_type) << std::endl;
                           ^
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the size of the contained type?

Comment: Use `std::vector<uint>::value_type`

Comment: `sizeof(std::vector<uint>::value_type)` or `sizeof(decltype(vecs)::value_type)`.

Comment: Thanks, the decltype trick is what I used. If you can find the time can you please post a detailed explanation what is going on here? I think I have a vague idea but not enough that I might explain it in detail.

Comment: Why not simply `sizeof(vecs[0])`?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Would that work even if the vector has zero elements?

Comment: Yes, because the operand is not evaluated. (Yeah I'm late. :|)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**3.4.3 Qualiﬁed name lookup [basic.lookup.qual]**

> 1 The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be
>   referred to after the :: scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to a
>   nested-name-speciﬁer that denotes its class, namespace, or
>   enumeration. If a :: scope resolution operator in a
>   nested-name-speciﬁer is not preceded by a decltype-speciﬁer, lookup of
>   the name preceding that :: considers only namespaces, types, **and
>   templates whose specializations are types**. If the name found does not
>   designate a namespace or a class, enumeration, or dependent type, the
>   program is ill-formed.

In this case, you are accessing a `type` member from the class template specialization `std::vector<uint>`, and you need to do it by writing:

```
std::vector<uint>::value_type
```

In case you are actually inside templated code and want to e.g. access the same nested type, you need to prefix it with the keyword `typename` like this:

```
typename std::vector<T>::value_type
```

In C++11, you can use `sizeof(decltype(vecs)::value_type)` or also `sizeof(decltype(vecs.back()))`, the latter is convenient if you don't know the precise name of the type but know how to access them through a member function like `back()`.

**Note**: as pointed out by @Casey in the comments, `decltype` requires stripping references in order to get the type itself, but for sizeof purposes that doesn't matter.

Comment: Re. the last paragraph, both `.` and `->` can be used to access `static` data members or functions, which are *class* members. It just cannot be used to access a type.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas tnx, I removed that section as I don't want to go into all that detail about `.`.

Comment: ...and enumerators! Let us not neglect the poor defenseless enumerators.

Comment: Nit: `decltype(vecs.back())` is `decltype(vecs)::value_type&` and requires stripping with `std::remove_reference` or `std::decay` to get to the pure type.

Comment: @Casey tnx, but for `sizeof()` purposes, that isn't necessary. Updated though.

Comment: Note that `decltype(vecs)::value_type` won't work if `vecs` is a `std::vector<T>&`.  It's necessary to use the even more cumbersome `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(vecs)>::value_type`.

Comment: Since `sizeof()` can be passed an expression, not just a type, it's not necessary to use `decltype()` to turn an expression into its type.  E.g., `sizeof('x')` is valid as is, there is no need to write `sizeof(decltype('x'))`.  This leads to what I think is the best answer to the original question.  Get the size using `sizeof(vecs[0])`.  It's perfectly safe to use `std::vector::operator[]` in this unevaluated context.  It's very concise and it works for vectors, other containers, and even C arrays or pointers.  E.g., in a template where the type of `vecs` could be many things besides vector.

Answer (score 14):

The member access operator `.` can only be used to access data members and member functions of classes, not other nested names such as type names. You'll need the scope resolution operator `::` to access them, and that can only be applied to the class name (or an alias), not an object of class type:

```
std::vector<uint>::value_type
```

In C++11 or later, `decltype` can give you a type name, if you have an object and no convenient access to the type:

```
decltype(vecs)::value_type
```

Comment: Nitpick nazi says: Nested types *are* members of classes §9.2/1 "Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested types, and enumerators", but they are specifically excluded from member access expressions §5.2.5/4 "If `E2` is a nested type, the expression `E1.E2` is ill-formed."

Comment: @Casey: Thanks, I wasn't sure of the precise definition of "member". The answer is more correct now.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer the more concise:

```
sizeof(vecs[0])
```

Which at first glance seems unsafe because what happens when `vecs` is a zero length vector?

For this example where the argument to `sizeof()` operator is called on a value type, the `sizeof()` operator is executed at compile time and so `vecs[0]` can never cause a segfault or crash.

p.s. `sizeof()` is only evaluated at runtime when the argument is a variable-length-array (from C or GNU C++ extension)

Answer (score 3):

The comments pretty much said it all: if you know the type of the vector, you can use `sizeof(std::vector<uint>::value_type)`. Otherwise use `sizeof(decltype(vecs)::value_type)`.

`decltype` is a magical C++11 construct that evaluates to the type of its argument, so the code

```
int i;
float f;

decltype(i) j;
decltype(f) g;
```

Is the same as

```
int i;
float f;

int j;
float g;
```

Only use the `.` operator for fields and methods (technically it can be used for static variable as well, but it's considered bad practice). For anything else, such as static variables, inner classes, or class-scope template parameters or typedefs (such as `value_type`), use the scope-resolution operator `::`.