# How to use lambda auto parameters in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I have a code in C++14. However, when I used it in C++11, it has an error at `const auto`. How to use it in C++11?

```
vector<vector <int> > P;  
std::vector<double> f;
vector< pair<double, vector<int> > > X; 
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        X.push_back(make_pair(f[i],P[i]));

////Sorting fitness descending order
stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend());
std::stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend(),
                [](const auto&lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
```

Comment: Yeah, edits that fundamentally change the question are really not appropriate here, I've removed it. I understand that you don't post here much and that what you did *is* commonly accepted on forums, so I can understand why you did it, but it's okay to ask plenty of related separate questions here, as long as they're all good questions that make sense on their own.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

C++11 doesn't support **generic lambdas**. That's what `auto` in the lambda's parameter list actually stands for: a generic parameter, comparable to parameters in a function template. (Note that the `const` isn't the problem here.)

> Note: C++14 *does* support lambdas with `auto`, `const auto`, etc.  You can read about it [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas).

You have basically *two options*:

1. Type out the *correct type* instead of `auto`. Here it is the element type of `X`, which is `pair<double, vector<int>>`. If you find this unreadable, a typedef can help.

   ```
   std::stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend(),
                    [](const pair<double, vector<int>> & lhs,
                       const pair<double, vector<int>> & rhs)
                    { return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
   ```
2. Replace the lambda with a functor which has a *call operator template*. That's how generic lambdas are basically implemented behind the scene. The lambda is very generic, so consider putting it in some global utility header. (However do not `using namespace std;` but type out `std::` in case you put it in a header.)

   ```
   struct CompareFirst {
       template <class Fst, class Snd>
       bool operator()(const pair<Fst,Snd>& l, const pair<Fst,Snd>& r) const {
           return l.first < r.first;
       }
   };
   ```

   ```
   std::stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend(), CompareFirst());
   ```

Answer (score 15):

I know there is an accepted answer, but you can also use `decltype` in C++11 for this, it looks a bit messy...

```
stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend(), [](decltype(*X.cbegin()) lhs, decltype(lhs) rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
```

Use `cbegin()` here as you get the const correct `value_type` of the container.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, generic lambdas that take `auto` (whether `const` or not) is a C++14 only feature.

See here https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas for some more details.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can directly use the `value_type` typedef of the container with a `decltype`, like

```
std::stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend(),
                 [](const decltype(X)::value_type & lhs, 
                    const decltype(X)::value_type & rhs)
                    {return lhs.first < rhs.first; }
                );
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can simply type `X.value_type` instead of `decltype(X)::value_type`.

Comment: @leemes I don't think so, `value_type` is a nested `typedef` so you need scope access via `::`. Live [here](http://ideone.com/fAMF40), and related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21290875/3093378).

Comment: Thanks, then I'm happy that my brain threw a warning when I thought that it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

`const auto` is not supported in C++11 as a lambda parameter (actually generic lambdas are not supported in C++11).

To fix:

```
using pair_type = std::pair<double, std::vector<int>>;
vector<pair_type> X;

std::stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend(),
                [](const pair_type&lhs, const pair_type& rhs)
                { return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
```