# Compiletime for each with custom functions

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

### Abstract:

Imagine a problem of the following form: One has to invoke multiple specific member functions with the same parameters on a list of functors. That makes a good problem to solve with an interface (runtime_interface, in other words a requirement of functions that those functors have to implement). The Problem I would like to discuss is the case where the list of functors is known at compile time, but might be subject to change during the further development process. Because in this case if implemented like that one is paying the runtime overhead even though all the functions to be called are known at compile time.

### General Question:

What are ways of solving Problems like the given one that come with no or just a small runtime overhead. without giving up the modularized structure.
I think what is really intresting about this is that its just

### My approach:

```cpp
template <class data_t, class... type_list_t>
struct compile_time_for_each_ref_impl;

template <class data_t, class first_t, class... type_list_t>
struct compile_time_for_each_ref_impl<data_t, first_t, type_list_t...> {
    static void eval(const data_t& data, first_t& object, type_list_t... object_list)
    {
        std::apply(object, data);

        compile_time_for_each_ref_impl<data_t, type_list_t...>::eval(data, object_list...);
    }
};
template <class data_t>
struct compile_time_for_each_ref_impl<data_t> {
    static void eval(const data_t& data) {}
};

template <class data_t, class... type_list_t>
void compile_time_for_each(const data_t& data, type_list_t&... objects)
{
    compile_time_for_each_ref_impl<data_t, type_list_t...>::eval(data, objects...);
}

template <class data_t, class... type_list_t>
void compile_time_for_each(const data_t& data, std::tuple<type_list_t...>& objects)
{
    std::apply(
        [&data] (type_list_t... params) {
            compile_time_for_each_ref_impl<data_t, type_list_t...>::eval(data, params...);
        },
        objects);
}
```

### What I am able to:

```cpp
int data = 42

auto functor_1 = [] (int data) {std::cout << data;};
auto functor_2 = [] (int data) {data++; std::cout << data;};

compile_time_for_each(std::make_tuple(data), functor1, functor2);
```

### What the code i would like to write looks like::

```cpp
struct functor1{
    void method1(int);

    int method2(double);
};


struct functor1{
    void method1(int);

    int method2(double);
};

template <class... functors_t>
struct main_mod{
    std::tuple<functors_t...> functors;

    void method1(int some_data){
        compile_time_for_each<method1, functors_t...>(some_data,functors);
    }

    void method2(int some_data){
        compile_time_for_each<method2, functors_t...>(some_data,functors);
    }
};
```

### The problem with my approach:

I dont see a way to pass the name of the function that is supposed to be called on the functor to the compile_time_for_each call. What i could do is to change the hardcoded function name (the example implementation takes the operator() because it makes the code simpler the code but one could hardcode any funtion name) so i would end up with one compile_time_for_each function for every function name that i would like to use.

### One Solution(that I dont like to much):

A valid solution would be to make that whole thing a macro and set the actual name of the function in the macro.

At the end for me it is not really about the overhead but not beeing able to express theese things properly.

### My actual implementation draft:

It incorporates @Aconcagua's idea of the resolver and the usage of fold expressions that @max66 suggested aswell. In this state I have not done any optimizations but I like the Interface and that was my main goal. Even though I think it should be doable without any overhead. If you are seeing this and have any ideas or suggestions hit me up.

https://godbolt.org/z/LfmSSb

Comment: maybe add a "What I would like to do" section with the code you would like to write. I dont understand what you want to do

Comment: btw your "What I can do" has some syntax errors. Why not fix them and turn it into real code, aka a [mcve]

Comment: why did you tag c++17 and c++20? The c++xy tags are for question regarding the specific versions of the standard. For question about the current standard the c++ tag is fine

Comment: I will change the example so it compiles. The reason why I put those tags is that I need features from thos standarts for this implementation and I do not care about solutions that work in older versions of the standard.

Comment: ... or try to explain what you mean with "[...] but this requires me to have a lot of kinda duplicated code" you are refering to code in the example?

Comment: To be honest I think that this approach only makes sense with c++20 concepts which actually gives u a way to express those "compiletime interfaces" in c++.

Comment: "To be honest I think that this approach only makes sense with c++20 concepts" then you should mention that in the question. As far as I can tell your code is not using concepts and the tag alone is rather confusing. Dont use tags to predict what could be an answer. Imho it'd be fine to tag as c++ and mention in the question that you would be ok with using c++20 concepts...

Comment: I think it might be best to split the question into two different ones because im mixing up finding a solution to a general problem (creating a pattern?) and the problem I have with that specific implementation.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this. "To be honest I think that this approach only makes sense with c++20 concepts" this is only something that would make the interface more user friendly but it is not directly realted to solving the problem so dont bother.

Comment: maybe first clarify this one :P. Where is the duplicated code you want to avoid?

Comment: for example consider a report generation module that computes a number of subreports on the same data. One could implement that by creating a subreport interface and the report generation module with having a list of objects implementing that interface. But when i know the subreport modules i want to use at compile time then i have to hardcode them and pay for the polymorphoc behaviour even though im not using it

Comment: the other no overhead approach is to copy that submodule functions into the report generation module. Than I end up with no runtime overhead but i loose the advantages of the modularized design.

Comment: the problem is that my current implementation only works with the function that is supposed to be called in the compiletime foreach hardcoded. But when i need an "interface" with more than one function I always have to copy the compiletime foreach and hardcode the next function name. But that is creating so much redundant code that the effort of implementing something like this is just not worth it.(f.e. the function hardcoded is the operator(), but i could write one  calling std::invoke(&first_t::hardcoded_function_name, object, ....)

Comment: Your compiler might already be able to unroll the corresponding loop itself (if necessary by adding some pragmas): https://godbolt.org/z/F2BGFO. And even if it doesn't check how much runtime overhead you actually save by that. In some situations it is more efficient to not unroll loops (e.g., if instruction cache is the bottleneck)

Comment: thank u for your thoughts but as I added to the uptdated version of the question I do not really care about the overhead but more about the general way to express things like that because and i think that an interface like that allows u to write highly reusable and easily extendable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a lambda I managed to get pretty close to what you intend, even though I failed to provide an exact match:

```
template<typename Executor, typename Data, typename ... Functors>
void for_each(Executor executor, Data const& data, Functors ... functors)
{
    // C++17 fold expression:
    (executor(functors, data), ...);
}

class C0
{
public:
    void test0(int) const { std::cout << "00" << std::endl; }
    void test1(int) const { std::cout << "01" << std::endl; }
};
class C1
{
public:
    void test0(int) const { std::cout << "10" << std::endl; }
    void test1(int) const { std::cout << "11" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    for_each([](auto const& c, int data) { c.test0(data); }, 7, C0(), C1());
    for_each([](auto const& c, int data) { c.test1(data); }, 7, C0(), C1());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer since it actually does what I was trying to achieve. What I do not understand is that even though templates require you to pass types  and templates that are not fully specified are not considered types you are able to pass this lambda which acts like a template right(in the way that its actual implementation depends on the type it is evaluated on)?

Comment: @bigh Although pretty different question, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071501/1312382) (second option!) should shed some light on...

Comment: Damn now I get it what is templated is the operator() and not the actual functor. Thank you again for looking up that useful reference I think now I got everything in place to implement it how I would like to.

Comment: I just put the updated version into the original question. If you are interested feel free to look it up. I would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations.

1) if you want a compile time execution, you have to use `constexpr`.

So your `compile_time_for_each()` must be defined `constexpr` if you want that can be executed compile time

```
template <typename data_t, typename... type_list_t>
constexpr void compile_time_for_each (data_t const & data, type_list_t &... objects)
 { /* some potentially compile time code */  }
```

2) a `constexpr` function can be executed both compile time and run time; if you want impose that is executed compile-time... maybe there are other ways but the simplest mode come in my mind is return a value from the function

```
template <typename data_t, typename... type_list_t>
constexpr int compile_time_for_each (data_t const & data, type_list_t &... objects)
 {
   /* some potentially compile time code */

   return 1;
 }
```

and use the returned value to initialize a `constexpr` variable

```
constexpr auto x = compile_time_for_each(data, functor_1, functor_2);
```

3) for a compile time execution, you needs compile-time values, so define `data` as `constexpr`

```
constexpr int data = 42;
```

or its use prevents the compile time execution.

4) there is no needs of recursion: you tagged C++17 so you can use template folding; by example

```
template <typename D, typename ... Fs>
constexpr int compile_time_for_each (D const & data, Fs const & ... funcs)
 {
   (std::apply(funcs, data), ...);

   return 0;
 }
```

5) iostream input/output code isn't compatible with compile-time execution; so the following lambdas

```
 auto functor_1 = [] (int data) {std::cout << data;};
 auto functor_2 = [] (int data) {data++; std::cout << data;};
```

can't be executed compile-time.

---

The following is a C++17 example

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename D, typename ... Fs>
constexpr int ct_for_each (D const & data, Fs const & ... funcs)
 {
   (std::apply(funcs, data), ...);

   return 0;
 }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr int data = 42;

   auto constexpr functor_1 = [] (int data) { /* some_code_1 */ };
   auto constexpr functor_2 = [] (int data) { /* some_code_2 */ };

   // compile time error if you define functor_1 as follows
   // auto constexpr functor_1 = [] (int data) { std::cout << data << std::endl; };

   constexpr auto x = ct_for_each(std::make_tuple(data), functor_1, functor_2);

   (void)x; // to avoid "unused variable 'x'" warning
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your submission. Maybe the name is a bit misleading but i dont want the functors to be evaluated at compile time but let the compiler unfold subfunctions into the fucntion that is supposed to be called. I updated the question in the mean time mybe its cleare what i want ot archieve now.

Comment: @bigh - Yes... is a bit misleading. What you're looking for isn't template folding?

Comment: I did not know about the template folding syntax I will update the question accordingly. I cant upvote your answer since I do not have enough rep to.But since the answer is not the answer to the actual question I am not accepting it like that.