# Passing one function name to template to use several overloads of it inside template body

Tags: c++, c++14

I have class with some calls inside. Every call taking like an argument two callbacks: for successful and error case respectivelly. Inside of these callbacks I have to call for both cases overloaded function with name like "answerCallName", but pass different params to it depending on success.

So with rising a number of such calls it becomes annoying to define for every call two callback inside.

So I'm searching the solution better than "copy paste".
I'm looking on templates. But cannot find any way to use one function name like argument to use it for different overloads inside template.

I've tried to make some templates, but obviously failed, so far as template requeres exect function pointer and in case function is overloaded I need to explicitly show this type.

```
//========================================================
//Here is exaple of class (library) with a lot of calls
class SomeLargeClass
{
protected: 
   void callToDoSmth1(std::function<void(int)>, std::function<void(std::string)>);
   void callToDoSmth2(std::function<void(char)>, std::function<void(std::string)>);
   void callToDoSmth3(std::function<void(const A & a)>, std::function<void(std::string)>);
   ...
};

//========================================================
//Here is calls I should call when one of callbacks are called. Also this part is placed in the library
class ResponsesClass
{
protected: 
 void answerCallToDoSmth1(int);
 void answerCallToDoSmth1(std::string);

 void answerCallToDoSmth2(char);
 void answerCallToDoSmth2(std::string);

 void answerCallToDoSmth3(const A & a);
 void answerCallToDoSmth3(std::string);

  ...
}

//========================================================
//Here is my class
class MyProxy: public SomeLargeClass, public ResponsesClass
{
...
   void action1();
}

//========================================================
//
void MyProxy::action1()
{
   auto success = [](int value)
     {
        ResponsesClass::answerCallToDoSmth1(value);
     }

   auto error = [](std::string value)
     {
        ResponsesClass::answerCallToDoSmth1(value);
     }

   SomeLargeClass::callToDoSmth1(success, error); 
}
```

So I'm looking for something like:

```
template<class ResponseFn, class ReturnType, class Object>
std::pair<
   std::function<void(ReturnType)>,
   std::function<void(std::string)>
>
MyProxy::createCallbacks(ResponseFn responseFn, Object object)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
{
   auto onSuccess = [this, responseFn] (ReturnType value)
   {
      (object->*responseFn)(value);
   };

   auto onError = [object, responseFn](std::string value)
   {
      (object->*responseFn)(value);
   };
   return std::pair<decltype(onSuccess), decltype(onError)>(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

to create callbacks for every call with one function call.

```
void MyProxy::actionX()
{
   auto callbacks = createCallbacks<int>(&MyProxy::answerCallToDoSmthX); //not working due to diffrent function addresses
   SomeLargeClass::callToDoSmthX(callbacks.first, callbacks.second); 
}
```

I'm just intresting could it be solved without makroses and generators. 
Is it planned to be resolved in future standarts?

Comment: What C++ standard are you using?

Comment: A very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180174/compiletime-for-each-with-custom-functions); maybe even duplicate?

Comment: I'm using с++14.

Comment: @Aconcagua, Sorry, I'm not sure I can find something related to my situation. I looked through several times, but haven't seen how to transform one function name to different overloads of it inside template.
It's easy to achieve just making separate argument for every ```answerCallToDoSmthX``` overload respectevelly in function ```createCallbacks```. 
But I'm triyng to find some solution to avoid it and use only one param. 
So far as function name is known and I can specify which overload of it will be used inside template, I guess it should be possible somehow to deduce address of them.

Comment: I think a base class with 2 virtual functions (for success and error) and a virtual destructor would suit your situation much better than templates and it would be easier to maintain, you only have to know the data on construction of the derived classes. Depends really a lot on how the rest of your code looks though, the example is too generic for offering an optimal answer

Comment: @xception, could you please show a short example of solution you proposed? 
I have about hundred possible parameter types for successful case and I cannot catch how I could resolve multiplication of the almost the same code without templates (and lambdas mentioned by "sebrockm").
I have a parts which cannot be changed: ```SomeLargeClass``` and ```ResponsesClass```. I want to implement handling like in ```actionX```. 
Current version of  every ```actionX``` contains two labda definitions, which I'm going to place in ```createCallbacks`` to reduce body of every "actionX".

Comment: I'm sorry, my initial understanding was that you could change `SomeLargeClass` or at least `ResponsesClass`. Since they can't be changed it's really hard to come with a solution that doesn't involve either templates or macros. And you seem to have found your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++14 lambdas can have `auto` parameters:

```
void MyProxy::action1()
{
   auto success_and_error = [=](auto... value)
     {
        ResponsesClass::answerCallToDoSmth1(value...);
     };

   SomeLargeClass::callToDoSmth1(success_and_error, success_and_error); 
}
```

This effectively makes the lambda's `operator()` a variadic template function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters. That way the lambda can implicitly be converted to `std::function<void(int)>`, `std::function<void(std::string)>`, `std::function<void(std::string, int, float, int, A, B, C)>`, and whatever else you like, as long as there is a corresponding overload of `SomeLargeClass::callToDoSmth1()` that takes the same parameters.

Comment: interesting, but I think his problem was actually getting the names of the different function names to be different inside the lambda (that is in case I understood the question correctly

Comment: @xception hmmm... you may be right. Let's wait for OP to clarify

Comment: @sebrockm,
Actually I need a function which would get function name and return std::pair which two known implementations of this function like a std::function instance of predefined signature. 

```lang-c++
using tSuccessCb  std::function<void(int)>;
using tErrorCb  std::function<void(std::string)>;

std::pair<tSuccessCb, tErrorCb> create( "function name through the params")
{
    auto success = [] (int)
    {
        //function which name passed overrided to int
    };

    auto error = [](std::string)
{
 //function which name passed overrided to std::string
}}
```

Comment: @АлексейСмиян Function names are just like variable names. If passed as param to another function, inside of that function it is impossible to determine if those params were called `callToDoSmth1` or `callToDoSmth2` on the caller side. However, the lambda in my answer captures the the right name for you, in this case `answerCallToDoSmth1` and thus calls it. So, you cannot author a function like your `create`-idea and call it. But you can instead create a lambda like in my answer. It's a really short lambda, so it's just a little more typing than calling `create(<function name>)`.

Comment: @sebrockm, sorry, I cannot catch the idea first time. Yes you are right. It works fine!)
Seems this is correct answer for case I mentioned. 
But it will not work for case when calbacks have different number of params for instance, will it?

Comment: also this solution is not allowed to have some differentiation between error and success case.

Comment: @АлексейСмиян "But it will not work for case when calbacks have different number of params" I cannot find this requirement in you question. Could you update it? Anyway, I updated my answer so that this will work, too. "also this solution is not allowed to have some differentiation between error and success case." Well, your code doesn't have this, either. It relies on the error function taking an `std::string` and the success function to take anything else. My solution has the same limitation. As long as in the error case there is a string and in the success case there is not, it will work.

Comment: Yes you are right. A lot of details which were hidden with simplifying the question) 
Anyway in my current situation your solution looks verry nice. I'm just looking for the tresholds. And yes, updated unswer more sutable for my case now. Thanks.